# Rspec "specify" one line block with tested field name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Take a look at this code snippet:

```
context "first row" 
  specify { subject[0][:monthly_total].should be_nil }
  specify { subject[0][:yearly_total].should be_nil }
  specify { subject[0][:total].should be_nil }
end
```

This works fine. The problem is that when I run `rspec --format documentation` the readability of the specs is compromised:

```
...
first row
  should be_nil
  should be_nil
  should be_nil
...
```

I would like the name of the variable being checked to be displayed - I don't care if I have to manually input it as a string literal or if it gets extracted from the code. I also want to avoid doing it with the multiline `it` block, as the assertion is really simple. Is there a way to do it?

`specify "variable name" { variable.should be_nil }` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `its` syntax.

```
context "first row" do
  subject { your_object[0] }
  its([:monthly_total]) { should be_nil }
  its([:yearly_total])  { should be_nil }
  its([:total])         { should be_nil }
end
```

[Doc here.](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/subject/attribute-of-subject)

---

Tip: to reuse your former `subject`, give it a name!

```
subject(:my_model) { ... }

context "first row" do
  subject { my_model[0] }
```